# Python FTP download 550 error

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I've written an ftp crawler to download specific files. It works up until it finds the specific file it wants to download, and then it throws this error:

```
ftplib.error_perm: 550
```

The file exists in my download folder, but the size of the file is 0 kb.
Do I need to convert something in order to get it to download?.
I can access the ftp manual and download the file without any problems, so don't think it's the login part (unless there's different ways of logging in??)

Here's my code:

```
import ftplib
import re
import os


class Reader:

def __init__(self):

    self.data = ""

def __call__(self,s):

    self.data += s + "\n"

ftp = ftplib.FTP("my_ftp_server")

ftp.login()

r = Reader()

ftp.dir(r)

def get_file_list(folder):



    r = Reader()

    ftp.dir(folder, r)

    print ("Reading folder",folder)


    global tpe
    global name
    for l in r.data.split("\n"):

        if len(l) > 0:
            vars = re.split("[ ]*", l)
            tpe = vars[2]
            name = vars[3]
        if tpe == "<DIR>":

            get_file_list( folder + "/" + name )
        else:
            print (folder + name)
        for name in folder:
            if vars[3].endswith(('501.zip','551.zip')):
                if os.path.exists('C:\\download\\' + vars[3]) == False:
                    fhandle = open(os.path.join('C:\\download\\', vars[3]), 'wb')
                    print ('Getting ' + vars[3])
                    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + vars[3], fhandle.write)
                    fhandle.close()
                elif os.path.exists(('C:\\download\\' + vars[3])) == True:
                    print ('File ', vars[3], ' Already Exists, Skipping Download')

print("-"*30)
print ("Fetching folders...")

get_file_list("")
```

Comment: You should probably `split` on `" +"` instead. Zero-width splits tend not to do what you expect.

Comment: Doing " +" insted of "[ ]*" didn't make any difference though. Still getting the ftplib.error_perm: 550

Comment: It wasn't meant to solve your problem, but I rhunk that's broken too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is probably OK.

FTP error 550 is caused by a permission issue on the server side.

This error means 'Requested action not taken. File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).', as you can find out [here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

If you expect to have access to it, you should contact the sysadmin to rectify the file permission.

Comment: Funny thing is though, that you can enter the FTP IP manually and access the FTP and download any file you want. Could it be the retrbinary format?. Does the code I wrote work for .zip files?