# How to avoid getting ftplib.error_perm: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm writting a python code to upload many image files to a FTP server with ftplib for my company, but my code must be applied for network instability. Therefore, when a image file is uploading to FTP server, maybe it will fail, and then I get an error "**ftplib.error_perm: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**". By the way, the FTP server is managed by another company.

My uploading image files code:

```py
with open(img_list[0][0], "rb") as oFile:
    check_chars = oFile.read()[-2:]
# End of with-block
if check_chars != b"\xff\xd9":
    time.sleep(1)
    continue
# End of if-condition

print("準備上傳： %s" %(img_list[0][1]))
if cut_switch:
    img = Cut_image(img_list[0][0])
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+img_list[0][1], img)
else:
    with open(img_list[0][0], 'rb') as imageReader:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR '+img_list[0][1], imageReader)
    # End of with-block
# End of if-else-condition
```

I hope somebody could gives me suggestions to solve the error, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python FTP download 550 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659470/python-ftp-download-550-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    oFile = open(img_list[0][0], "rb") 
    check_chars = oFile.read()[-2:]
    if check_chars != b"\xff\xd9":
        time.sleep(1)
    oFile.close()

    print("準備上傳： %s" %(img_list[0][1]))
    if cut_switch:
        img = Cut_image(img_list[0][0])
        ftp.storbinary('STOR '+img_list[0][1], img)
    else:
        with open(img_list[0][0], 'rb') as imageReader:
            ftp.storbinary('STOR '+img_list[0][1], imageReader)
```

The error occur because you haven't close the file (you are opening it)
And you should remember that you don't need to `continue` to quit the if-else condition

Comment: I have tried your suggestions, but I still get the error. The error always occurs when an image is uploading.